# How to simplify (reduce number of points) in KML?

Tags: google-maps, maps, kml

I have a similar problem to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174535/google-maps-overlays). I need to display up to 1000 polygons on an embedded Google map. The polygons are in a SQL database, and I can render each one as a single KML file on the fly using a custom HttpHandler (in ASP.NET), like this http://alpha.foresttransparency.org/concession.1.kml .

Even on my (very fast) development machine, it takes a while to load up even a couple dozen shapes. So two questions, really:

1. What would be a good strategy for rendering these as markers instead of overlays once I'm beyond a certain zoom level?
2. Is there a publicly available algorithm for simplifying a polygon (reducing the number of points) so that I'm not showing more points than make sense at a certain zoom level?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For your second question: you need the [Douglas-Peucker Generalization Algorithm](http://everything2.com/index.pl?node_id=859282)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I needed. I've adapted a C# implementation of D-P I found on CodeProject - seems to work pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

For your first question, could you calculate the area of a particular polygon, and relate each zoom level to a particular minimum area,  so as you zoom in or out polygon's disappear and markers appear depending on the zoom level.

For the second question, I'd use Mark Bessey's suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much aobut KML, but I think the usual solution to question #2 involves iterating over the points, and deleting any line segments under a certain size. This will cause some "unfortunate" effects in some cases, but it's relatively fast and easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend 2 things:
- Calculate and combine polygons that are touching. This involves a LOT of processing and hard math, but I've done it so I know it's possible. 
- Create your own overlay instead of using KML in PNG format, while you combine them in the previous suggestion. You'll have to create a LOT of PNGs but it is blazing fast on the client.

Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks - I really don't have the resources to duplicate so much of what the Google API provides for free.

Answer (score 0):

I needed a solution to your #2 question a little bit ago and after looking at a few of the available line-simplification algorithms, I created my own.

The process is simple and it seems to work well, though it can be a bit slow if you don't implement it correctly:

**`P[0..n]`** is your array of points
 Let **`T[n]`** be defined as the triangle formed by points **`P[n-1], P[n], P[n+1]`**
 **`Max`** is the number of points you are trying to reduce this line to.

1. Calculate the area of every possible triangle `T[1..n-1]` in the set.
2. Choose the triangle `T[i]` with the smallest area
3. Remove the point `P[i]` to essentially flatten the triangle
4. Recalculate the area of the affected triangles `T[n-1], T[n+1]`
5. Go To Step #2 if the number of points > `Max`

Comment: Out of curiosity, why not go with Douglas-Peucker? At first glance your algorithm seems considerably less efficient. It also aims for a fixed number of points, rather than a given tolerance - so how would you apply it to a large number of shapes of differing complexity?

Comment: You know...   I might try implementing that soon.  This part of my app gets run pretty infrequently, but looking at it again, it does look like a better method.   Thanks.